# 11.04 on MacBook Pro 7,1?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, macbook

On [Ubuntu MacBookPro support page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro), I've found info about [10.10 on MBP 7,1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Maverick) and some info about [11.04 on MBP 8,1+](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-1/Natty). But what I would like is information about 11.04 on MBP 7,1. The issues I'm most concerned about:

- does WiFi work? OotB?
- does external monitor work? OotB?

EDIT: additional info

wifi

```
Card Type:  AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x8D)
Firmware Version:   Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.36.1)
```

graphics card

```
Chipset Model:  NVIDIA GeForce 320M
```

Comment: audio and video chipsets would be useful...I have a sneaking suspicion it's a yes.  the last problem i remember with debianized and macbookpro was some weirdness with an nvidia sata controller that had to get sorted out.

Comment: youre running 64 bit right?

Comment: @TrevorMA: no, 32-bit PAE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just installed 11.04 on MBP, so I'm gonna answer my own question:

WiFi works. Not exactly out-of-the-box though. The [solution for 10.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606745) I've googled has helped in my case.

The original solution:

> 1. Go to *System>Administration>>Synaptic Package Manager* and in the search bar,
>      type `bcm`.
> 2. Make sure `broadcom-sta-common` and `broadcom-sta-source` are
>      installed. If not, mark them for
>      installation, close, and reload.
> 3. Make sure `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `bcmwl-modaliases` are installed.
>      If not install, reload, and then go
>      back and mark them for reinstallation.
>      Then reload.
> 4. Restart your computer. It won't tell you that you need to restart, but
>      it is necessary nonetheless.
> 5. After you have restarted, click on the network icon at the top and click
>      on "Connect to Hidden Wireless
>      Network..."
> 6. Enjoy your wifi connection...hopefully.

Actually in my case I didn't have to install `bcmwl-modaliases`, nor did I have to use hidden network option (Ubuntu detected all networks perfectly).

---

External monitor works, almost OotB. All you need is to install `disper` to actually activate it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:disper-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install disper
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently installing 11.04 in my macbook white. It's almost the same hardware as your macbook pro. Everything's fine until now. Got wireless out of the box and it's working well. WHen the installations ends I'll see if video works.